# Connexity of points in the plane that have at least one rational coordinate

Tags: general-topology

the question is in the title. Basically, I want to show that $X := (\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{Q}) \cup (\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{R})$ is connected. In order to do that, I want to define $f: [0, 1] \to X$ continuous, which shows that $X$ is path-connected. However, I need help with the definition of $f$. My idea was to use the density of the set of rational numbers in the real numbers.

Thank you in advance,

derthomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us show that every element in $X$ is connected to $(0,0)$. If $(x,y) \in X$, then without loss of generality we may assume that $x \in \mathbb{Q}$. Then the map $f_1 : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^2, t \mapsto (x, (1-t) y)$ is a path to $(x,0)$ and it is completely contained in $\{x\} \times \mathbb{R} \subseteq \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{R} \subseteq X$. Now, the map $f_2 : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^2, t \mapsto ((1-t) x , 0)$ is a path connecting $(x,0)$ and $(0,0)$ in $\mathbb{R} \times \{0\} \subseteq \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{Q} \subseteq X$. 
We conclude that $(x,y)$ lies in the same path-connected component as $(0,0)$ and as $(x,y)$ was arbitrary it follows that $X$ is path-connected.

Note that we did not use any special property of $\mathbb{Q}$. In fact the proof above works with some minor changes for any set of the form $\mathbb{R} \times A \cup A \times  \mathbb{R}$ where $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is some non-empty subset of the reals.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, this was really helpful. So it is probably impossible to define only one funtion that is a path between $(0,0)$ and $(x,y)$, right? Since the line connecting these two points is not entirely included in $X$?

Comment: No, it is not impossible. Given two paths $f$ and $g$ with $f(1) = g(0)$ you can always form the path $h$ defined by $h(t) = f(2t)$ for $0 \leq t \leq \frac{1}{2}$ and $h(t) = g(2t - 1)$ for $\frac{1}{2} \leq t \leq 1$. This gives you a single path from $f(0)$ to $g(1)$.

Comment: Excuse me, I may have chosen the wrong words to formulate my question. What I wanted to know is if it is possible to define a continous function $f: [0,1]\to L$, where $L$ is the set of all points in $X$, lying on the line that connects $(0,0)$ and $(x,y)$.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, this is indeed impossible as there exists an irrational $t \in [0,1]$ such that $ty$ is irrational and then $(tx,ty)$ is not in $X$.

Comment: As we assume that $x\in Q$, I think that you mean "such that $tx$ is irrational", but yes, I see. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: No, I really mean that we need $ty$ to be irrational. If $t$ is any irrational number then $tx$ will be irrational as $x$ is rational. But we cannot take any irrational $t$ so that $ty$ is still irrational. For example if $(x,y) = (1, \pi)$, we cannot take $t = \frac{1}{\pi}$ (but $t = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ would work).

Comment: Ok, because the product of irrationals is not necessarily irrational. Now I got it, thanks again.